# How do i get all the data passing in WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I want to know how to get all the data passed on the WebSocket
I alredy tryied using FireFox to see but all the data are strange unicode text and symbols (game link is https://sploop.io) is there an way to maybe decrypt it?
I also tryied using

```js
var data= new WebSocket("usa1.sploop.io/ws")
data.onmessage = (sa)=>{console.log(sa)}
```

And after some actions in the game the code logged an object that didnt have any of the data...

Comment: Please tell me you are not trying to make a cheat or bot for this game.

Comment: I am not trying to make a cheat what i wanna make is an auto chat....

Answer (score 0):

You're already getting all the data the WebSocket is receiving. The problem is that the data is "encoded" binary data using the game's protocol. The scripts in Sploop.io know how to decode this data (and encode new data to be sent back), but since you don't "speak" that protocol, it looks like gibberish to you.

*Problem aside, you can have fun and all, but trying to cheat or so isn't nice towards other players.*

Comment: I dont wanna cheat all i want to make is an numpad auto chat like when a player press numpad1 he sends an message

Comment: Then try sending a chat message and check the outgoing WebSocket messages if you can spot the right message. Perhaps it's encoded in a way that's easy to replicate, otherwise you could comb through the JS code.

Comment: i sent some messages and it showed me this: https://prnt.sc/1jmmz8n